# Retrieving status data from printer/cartridge

Tags: windows, printing, status

I'm inquiring whether is is possible to get:

- ink/tone level of a printers cartridge
- the cartridge model number

The platform and programming language is free. But I'm most interested in a Windows solution.

Also do you know if there is some work in progress for a standard on communicating with the printer - or if some specific brands have something already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) is the standard for most laser printer.  Manufactures have a [MIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_Information_Base) that describes how to get the information from it, these are often widely available as they are used to provide large network management systems access to details about these devices.

Comment: I've looked a bit into the to SNMP and MIB - it seems like it is mostly larger/expensive and not consumer level equipment that uses these. And how do you go about accessing this information. Do you do?

Comment: If it is a very low-end device like an inkjet there probably isn't anything you can do.  This will mostly likely be proprietary communication between the driver, their own service software, port monitor and the printer.  Most network enabled devices do support SNMP in some capacity but USB type solutions don't have a standard for this type of information.